# Using in Java TimerTask in spark is not working

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use java timertask class in spark ,It is working in local but when i deploy in cluster it is not working . The job is getting finished by doing nothing

Comment: "it is not working"- error or something?

Comment: Timer Task is scheduled for every 2 minutes it is working fine in local but when i am deploying in my cluster it is not working as expected, the job is getting completed with out doing anything.